# How to publish map to web using ArcGIS Desktop and Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, map-service

Just starting out with ArcGIS server at work, I've had no prior experience but I been given the responsibility to display our map on the web.

I have a ArcGIS server running on a server and I am using ArcMap 10 on my desktop.  I created a Folder in the server where I saved the map document.  I can add a new service using this document and I'm given a url when I do so.  But when I go to that URL I get this error:

`Server Error in '/ArcGIS/Services' Application.
Runtime Error`

And, when going to the same url from the server I get:
`Server Error in '/ArcGIS/Services' Application.
No Content`

I'm using ArcMap10 and ArcGIS server 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/ArcGIS/Services` application is actually a SOAP endpoint that won't give you anything when you visit it in a URL.  That's why you get the "No Content" error message - it's telling you that you didn't give it any instructions.

To actually see your map you will need to also deploy a viewer to your web server that can put that map into a browser.

The ArcGIS REST endpoint contains a simplified javascript viewer that you can use to verify that your map is working properly.  This is something that should work in your browser - replace 'Services' with 'REST' on the URL you have and you should see a list of published services.  For example:

http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services

From this list you can review the REST endpoint for a map, which has an "ArcGIS Javascript" link on the top, that lets you see the map in a viewer.  For example:

http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer?f=jsapi

Comment: Thank you, we actually have our own subdomain dedicated for map GIS map purposes, but I was able to see the service when I use mydomain/rest/Services.

Answer (score 3):

Once you publish a service in ArcGIS Server and in order to display that service over the web you will have to create a web application. In ArcGIS Server you can create the web applications from ArcGIS Server manager where in you can consume the service which you have published using the map document. For more detailed steps on how to create a new web application please go through the following link:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Creating_a_new_Web_application_in_Manager/009300000084000000/

Hope this will help you in displaying your map on the web .

Comment: Ok, so I've created the web application, but I'm getting another error

`Server Error in '/testMapApp' Application.
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\testmapapp\d4446e98\8a0b47f3\App_Code.compiled' is denied.`

I followed the path, but there is no file in that folder named `App_Code.compiled`, instead it has this file: `App_Code.t5iektdn.dll`

Comment: the temporary asp.net files folder requires some permission to network , service and IUSR accounts. Try giving them.. Also try registering iis with .NET framework.
From the following link try the point 3 under step 2.http://www.novell.com/support/viewContent.do?externalId=7920595

Answer (score 1):

To check out the Rest endpoint go to:

http://**Server Name**/ArcGIS/Rest/Services

If you're Programming an application yourself, then depending on the Application, you might need to use ArcGIS Rest Endpoint mentioned above.

Other wise you'll need to use a program like [GeoViewer 8](http://www.nobel-systems.com/products/gvpro.asp)